# Wordpress converts media extention URL automatically to video player

Tags: functions, urls, media, embed

I am new to Wordpress, learning one by one everyday.

I am having little problem in posting. When I add URL's in content which ends with .mp4 .wmv .mkv or any media related extension. It turns into video player automatically after posting. The browser displays video player instead of plain URL's.

How to disable this feature? I dont want any web player for my URL's. Just plain URL link which I set to clickable.

I am using Customizr child theme. The same happening in other themes too.

Please help and Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using the Auto-embeds Disabler plugin here: https://gist.github.com/ocean90/3796628

Note that it's actually just a single line of code, if you prefer to add that to your functions.php - but I'd suggest keeping it as a plugin so you can easily activate/deactivate that functionality.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', array( $GLOBALS['wp_embed'], 'autoembed' ), 8 );
```

Note that WordPress should only be automatically converting URLs, but NOT links.  If you create an actual link to the media item, WordPress should display it as a link as opposed to an embedded player.

Comment: Thank you very much !! I added that line in theme's functions.php and its working! no more web player.

If I added the links like _[embed]url here[/embed]_ its showing youtube player but not for plain .mp4 url's.

Thank you MadtownLems ^_^